# Trying to create 2 layouts in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

So I was trying to create a layout that takes 5 inputs from the user, with some text and another that opens and presents the 5 inputs from the previous layout.

Since I failed to do that, I tried having a button that switches between the two layouts but again, couldn't figure it out.

```
import PySimpleGUI as psg

psg.theme('BluePurple')

layout1 = [
    [psg.Text('Input1:', size=(15, 1)), psg.Input(expand_x=True)],
    [psg.Text('Input2:', size=(15, 1)), psg.Input(expand_x=True)],
    [psg.Text('Input3:', size=(15, 1)), psg.Input(expand_x=True)],
    [psg.Text('Input4:', size=(15, 1)), psg.Input(expand_x=True)],
    [psg.Text('Input5:', size=(15, 1)), psg.Input(expand_x=True)],
    [psg.OK(), psg.Cancel()]
]
layout2 = [
    [psg.Text('Output 1: ', values[0])],
    [psg.Text("Output 2 ", values[1], "years old")],
    [psg.Text("Output 3 ", values[2])],
    [psg.Text("Output 4"), values[3]],
    [psg.Text("Output 5 ", values[4])]
]
layout = [[psg.Column(layout1, key='COL1-'),psg.Column(layout2, visible=False, key='COL2-')]]
[psg.Button('Cycle Layout'), psg.Button('1'), psg.Button('2')]

window = psg.Window('Form', layout, size=(715, 207))

layout = 1
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event in(None, 'Exit'):
        break
    if event == 'Cycle Layout':
        window[f'COL{layout}-'].update(visible=False)
        layout = layout + 1 if layout < 2 else 1
        window[f'COL{layout}-'].update(visible=True)
    elif event in '123':
        window[f'COL{layout}-'].update(visible=False)
        layout = int(event)
        window[f'-COL{layout}-'].update(visible=True)

window.close()
```

I was expecting it to start but since 'values' unresolved it won't start, I can see how I was wrong, but I can't see how I can fix it. I've tried 3 different solutions and as I wait for answers on this I'm currently reading on more information on how I could probably fix this, but so far, I've hit a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

Left blank in second layout when initial, and update it after event.

You can update the output when input changed or before you switch the view.

Revised code as following

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('BluePurple')

layout0 = [
    [sg.Text(f'Input {i+1}:'),
     sg.Input(enable_events=True, expand_x=True, key=('IN', i))]
        for i in range(5)
]
layout1 = [
    [sg.Text(f'Output {i+1}:', expand_x=True, key=('OUT', i))]
        for i in range(5)
]
layout = [
    [sg.Column(layout0, key=('COL', 0), expand_x=True),
     sg.Column(layout1, key=('COL', 1), expand_x=True, visible=False)],
    [sg.VPush()],
    [sg.Push(),
     sg.Button('Cycle Layout'),
     sg.Button('1'),
     sg.Button('2'),
     sg.Button('Exit')],
]
window = sg.Window('Form', layout, size=(715, 207))
page = 0

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    elif isinstance(event, tuple) and event[0]=='IN':
        window[("OUT", event[1])].update(f'Output {event[1]+1}: {values[event]}')

    elif isinstance(event, str):
        if event == 'Cycle Layout':
            window[('COL', page)].update(visible=False)
            page = 1 - page
            window[('COL', page)].update(visible=True)

        elif event in '12':
            window[('COL', page)].update(visible=False)
            page = int(event) - 1
            window[('COL', page)].update(visible=True)

window.close()
```

Comment: I like the tuple keys... it's a good way to point out there's more than 1 and what they're used for... and the 2 pushes.... this is really good.